# Acting upon a different sheet

Tags: excel, button, vba

I have a button in a sheet named "INPUT". However, the code should be acting upon data located in a different sheet named "SUMBER" when I click that button. How do I do this?

```
Dim osh As Worksheet
Dim iRow As Long
Dim iCol As Long
Dim iFirstRow As Long
Dim iTotalRows As Long
Dim iStartRow As Long
Dim iStopRow As Long
Dim sSectionName As String
Dim rCell As Range
Dim owb As Workbook
Dim sFilePath As String
Dim iCount As Integer
Dim Response As Integer
Dim sFName As String

iCol = Worksheets("input").Range("B4")
iRow = Worksheets("input").Range("B5")
iFirstRow = iRow

Set osh = Application.ActiveSheet
Set owb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
iTotalRows = osh.UsedRange.Rows.Count
sFilePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
```

I've been trying to change these lines:

```
Set osh = Application.ActiveSheet
Set owb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
```

But it has not worked.

Comment: Do you mean you want them to refer to a different sheet? As in `Set osh = Worksheets("SUMBER")`?

Answer (score 0):

declare and set workbook and your sheets like this:

```
Dim owb as Workbook
Dim oshInput, oshSumber as Worksheet

Set owb = Thisworkbook
Set oshInput = owb.Sheets("Input")
Set oshSumber = owb.Sheets("Sumber")
```

then add what you want to do.
For example your line:

```
iCol = Worksheets("input").Range("B4")
iRow = Worksheets("input").Range("B5")
```

once you did the above declaration and set will be:

```
iCol = oshInput.Range("B4")
iRow = oshInput.Range("B5")
```

hope this helps and get's you started a bit.